# Как получить вектор структур данных из объекта nlohmann::json C++

Tags: c++, json, stl

Имеется структура

```
struct Color {
    uint8_t background;
    uint8_t foreground;

    Color() : 
        backgroung(0), foreground(15)
    {}
    Color(const uint8_t& bg, const uint8_t& fg) : 
        background(bg), foreground(fg)
    {}
}
```

И объект nlohmann::json _j

```
std::string obj = 
    "{ \"colors\": [ {\"background\": 0, \"foreground\": 1}, {\"background\": 0, \"foreground\": 4} ] }";
nlohmann::json _j = nlohmann::json::parse(obj);
```

Требуется в вектор :

```
std::vector<Color> vColors;
```

Поместить "colors" из объекта "_j"

Comment: `int ba = _j ["background"].get<int>();`

Comment: Элементов массива colors может быть неизвестное количество

Answer (score 0):

где то так

```
for (auto &color : obj["colors"]) {
  int c = color.value("background", 0);
  int f = color.value("foreground", 0);
  vColors.push_back(Color(c,f));
}
```

там может будут проблемы с преобразованием типов в конструкторе Color, но думаю, с этим справитесь

я использую синтаксис с value, потому что он в случае отсутствия ключа, возьмет дефолтное значение, которое написано в скобках.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: можно просто отметить галочку и/или нажать стрелку вверх:)